# JS/Apps Script: How do I map nested keys?

Tags: json, google-apps-script

In the following Google Apps Script code, I want to write three keys to the sheet `key_1`,`key_3.subkey` and `key_4[1].key`. How do fix my code to show the `subkey` and second element of `key_4` as well?

```
function main() {

  const data = [{"key_1":10,"key_2":20,"key_3":{"subkey":30},"key_4":[{"key":41},{"key":42}]},{"key_1":40,"key_2":50,"key_3":{"subkey":60},"key_4":[{"key":43},{"key":44}]}];
  const keys = ["key_1","key_3.subkey","key_4[1].key"];


  print(data, keys);

}

function print(data, keys) {

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  sheet.clear();

  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    arr = Array(keys.map(k => data[i][k]));
    sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,2).setValues(arr);
  }
}
```

Solution

```
function main() {
  const data = [{"key_1":10,"key_2":20,"key_3":{"subkey":30},"key_4":[{"key":41},{"key":42}]},{"key_1":40,"key_2":50,"key_3":{"subkey":60},"key_4":[{"key":43},{"key":44}]}];
  const keys = ["key_1","key_3.subkey","key_4.1.key"];
  print(data, keys);
}

function print(data, keys) {
  for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let arr = keys.map(k => k.split('.').reduce((a, b) => a[b], data[i]));
    Logger.log(arr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a format where all subkeys are separated by `.`. Then, you can split the string on `.` and use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to traverse the nested data structure.

```js
function main() {
  const data = [{"key_1":10,"key_2":20,"key_3":{"subkey":30},"key_4":["","4a"]},{"key_1":40,"key_2":50,"key_3":{"subkey":60},"key_4":["","4b"]}];
  const keys = ["key_1","key_3.subkey","key_4.1"];
  print(data, keys);
}
function print(data, keys) {
  for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let arr = keys.map(k => k.split('.').reduce((a, b) => a[b], data[i]));
    console.log(arr);
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I made one final edit to the data to match with the actual nesting. You answer is on point for the earlier dataset though, so thanks for that. Can you review it according to the updated data?

Comment: @Shantanu Use the string `"key_4.1.key"` instead in that case (for the last element of the array `keys`).